# execute() Call on async task it takes 1 second to call doInBackground() method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on async task. When i call `execute()` on async task it takes 1 second to call `doInBackground()` method of async task which I don't want. Does anyone knows how to reduce that time?

Comment: hi its default functionality. So we cant change it .

Comment: Taking care of 1 second...wow i can assume performance of your app.

Comment: i am almost convinced that that time cannot be reduced as its system level but trying to see if there is any help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such things are up to the System. Never assume anything about timing when working multithreaded!

Anyways, if your AsyncTask repeatedly does the same work, try using an ExecutorService which gets a Runnable as argument. The ExecutorServices don't destroy the created threads automatically but try to re-use it. That way the starttime might be reduced.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Exceutor, that was my second thought but i wasn't so sure that it will help me in reducing that time. Anyway i will try that once.

Answer (score 0):

One second to call `doInBackground()`, or one second to return a result? The reason for using an `AsyncTask` is to perform longer operations asynchronously from the UI thread. Performing operations that take a while (eg. 1 second) is why they exist.

Comment: its taking one second to call doInbackground() right when i call execute() on it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `execute()` use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ...)` That way you don't need an ExecutorService.